# Angular store a JSON array into `LocalStorage` and displaying on the html

Tags: json, local-storage, angular8

I'm sorry that I have asked a similar question but I have been struggling with this. As you can see from the `getById` is where the array is located on the page.

[Browser preview of the HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iwqz7.jpg)

Here is the typescript file:

```js
 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
 import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
 import { DashboardService } from '../dashboard.service';
 import { UserRole } from 'src/app/models/user';

 @Component({
     selector: 'app-dashboard',
     templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
     styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.scss']
 })
 export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

     constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, private dashboardService: DashboardService) {}
     accessToken = null;
     Userid = null;
     responseId = null;
     UserRoles = null;

     ngOnInit() {
         this.getById();
         this.accessToken = localStorage.getItem('accessToken');
         this.Userid = localStorage.getItem('UserId');
     }

     getById() {
         this.dashboardService.getUsersId(1).subscribe((res) => {
             console.log(res);
             this.responseId = res;
         })
     }
 }
```

The JSON response I'm trying to receive is like this:

```js
{
    "Id": 1,
    "Fullname": "test name",
    "Username": "test",
    "Password": "$2a$10$f.upx2WTxlriul4QK/1GSuCxd6Dmw7.NgVeJ2VfuiC0uIZai5rsD6",
    "PasswordSalt": "$2a$10$uCpbT0wAGFx5NxCwlZOkK.",
    "Enabled": true,
    "Locked": false,
    "Deleted": false,
    "LogonAttempts": 0,
    "LastLogon": null,
    "LastModifiedBy": "Tester",
    "LastModifiedOn": "2020-09-14T16:08:35.853Z",
    "CreatedBy": "Tester",
    "CreatedOn": "2020-09-14T16:08:35.853Z",
    "UserRoles": [{
        "Id": 3,
        "Roles": "Admin",
        "RolePermissions": [{
                "Id": 1,
                "Permission": "Administrator"
            },
            {
                "Id": 2,
                "Permission": "Currency"
            }
        ]
    }]
}
```

and my **HTML** page is like this:

```html
<p>Token: {{accessToken}}</p>
<a routerLink="titles" class="btn btn-primary mr-3">Titles</a>
<a routerLink="exercise-questions" class="btn btn-primary">Exercise Questions</a>
<a routerLink="customers" class="btn btn-primary">Customers</a>
<a routerLink="flavours" class="btn btn-primary">Flavours</a>
<p> UserID {{Userid}} </p>
<button class="btn btn-primary mr-3" (click)="getById()">Get By Id</button>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
        <h1>Get By Id</h1>
        <ul *ngIf="responseId != null">
            <li><span>Id: </span>{{responseId.Id}}</li>
            <li><span>Fullname </span>{{responseId.Fullname}}</li>
            <li><span>Last Logon: </span>{{responseId.LastLogon}}</li>
            <li><span>Role Permissions </span>{{responseId.UserRoles}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

All I wish to do is to save `Fullname`, `LastLogon` & `Role Permisisons` into localStorage and then to be able to display that on the html page.
So far I have been able to display `Fullname`, and `lastlogon` but haven't been able to store to the localStorage.

Answer (score 0):

Role Permissions is an array of objects, So to display in your html you have to do something like this:

```html
<li>
  <span *ngFor="let role of responseId.UserRoles">
     Id: {{ role.id }} - {{ role.Permission }}
  </span>
</li>
```

To store the desired values on localStorage simply create a function on your **DashboardComponent** and use `localStorage.setItem()` and `JSON.stringify()` for your `RolePermissions` like this:

**dashboard.component.ts**

```js
getById(){
  this.dashboardService.getUsersId(1).subscribe((res) => {
    console.log(res);
    this.responseId = res;
    this.StoreOnLocalStorage(res);
  })
}

StoreOnLocalStorage( data: any ) {
   localStorage.setItem("fullName", data.Fullname);
   localStorage.setItem("LastLogon", data.LastLogon);
   localStorage.setItem("RolePermissions", JSON.stringify(data.UserRoles[0].RolePermissions))
}
```

The result will be like this:

[image]

Comment: this is what i wanted thank you, only problem it is not displaying in html but hopefully i can work out why it isn't.

Comment: You're welcome, let me know if there is any problem. if you want to show the values based on the current values on LocalStorage, you can have a similar method which is get invoked on `ngOnInit()` and get the value from localStorage

Comment: thanks agian, if i could give karma i would :) and will remember that for the future re invoking with ngOnInit()

Comment: maybe you can help me here ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64027183/how-can-i-pass-all-localstorage-values-to-response           trying to move everything to a service.